# MATLAB how to turn off the yaxis created by 'yyaxis' command?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

How to turn off (totally) a yaxis in a Matlab figure?

Google only tell me how to create an extra yaxis.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Btw why are you creating it in the first place only to remove it later?

Comment: @Sardar_Usama Yeah I can also regenerate the figure, but that would spend some time. I am looking for a short cut here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the axis handle to modify either y axis.

```
hfig=figure;
hax=axes;
yyaxis(hax,'left')
hax.YAxis(1).Visible='off'; % Removes left axis
hax.YAxis(2).Visible='off'; % Removes right axis
```

Comment: Thank you! one more question: is it possible to exchange left and right axis?

Comment: As far as I know it isn't unless you switch each variable within hax.YAxis (YAxis itself is read only).